# CSS property to make short words move to next line?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to automatically detect if a line in text ends with short word and move it to next line? According that the text continues in next line.

In example I'd like the text:

```
Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a 
style sheet language used for describing 
the presentation semantics.
```

to be displayed as:

```
Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) 
is a style sheet language used for describing 
the presentation semantics.
```

Comment: There is no CSS property that will accomplish this.  You'll need to write a javascript function or find a JS library / plugin that does this.

Comment: Define "short word". Doesn't really matter anyway because CSS has no way to count characters and then perform an action.

Answer (score 2):

The example above cant be done in CSS, you will need to use Javascript - even then the implementation would likely be overkill. May I ask why you are after this effect? If it is purely aesthetic I'd advise you accept it as not having a readily available solution.

Comment: This should really be a comment not an answer unless you are going to suggest a way to implement it in JS.

Comment: Surely 'no' is a valid answer if that is indeed the case- similar to the results of a failed experiment remaining valid

Comment: @ExtPro, but it's possible in JS, so a JS sample would be useful.

Comment: I think this is fine as an answer.